# How to import variable from another file without running that program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to import variables from another program using the from import function.
Sample Code:

```
script1:
c=1
print('hello')

script2:
from script1 import c
```

When I run this my response is:

```
hello
10
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to make this run with only the variable c being shown.

Answer (score 7):

Move any code you don't want to run on import into the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, that's how it works.
If you want some code to not run, then move it to the section `__main__`:

```
import statements
code_that_runs()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_that_will_not_run_from_import()
```